# /mailFolders/inbox/messageRules HTTP 503

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

We're seeing an unexpected HTTP 503 returned consistently for one of our customers for Microsoft Graph for the following endpoint:
`GET /v1.0/users/<id>/mailFolders/inbox/messageRules`

We have a B2B product for managed service providers, and this same code implementation is working for thousands of our other deployments. But this individual customer is receiving an HTTP 503 during executions. My first guess here was that this may be a result of the customer being significantly larger than others, but:

I attempted to enable significant retry delay and back-off (and I looked but there was no "retry-after" header in the response). Delay with back-off from our side got up to a 6 second delay in some cases, but we still hit the HTTP 503.

I'm hesitant to include the mailbox ID for the user for this customer publicly, but I'd be happy to email that to someone from the Microsoft side.

Is there anything else I can do here? Based on some of the other posts I've found for 503s on the mailboxRules and related endpoints, I think this may be something on the Microsoft side.

(As an aside, is there any way I can get support for this outside of StackOverflow? I'm happy to provide non-redacted technical details over a private medium. Would that have to be through a customer's support contract rather than our own as we cannot reproduce the issue in-house?)

edit: minor formatting edit for GET endpoint

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a potential service issue so you can raise a support ticket through https://admin.microsoft.com and the team can assess this.